# change quantity button position in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

by default the quantity is right next to the button on left side, i want to change his position to above the button and add "quantity" text.

i try to use this solution but its bring me the box to the top:

i copy the `woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php`
to `themes/your-child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php`

after i remove the quantity script from the file

and insert some snippet:
`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'add_quantity_field_before_variations_form', 10 );
function add_quantity_field_before_variations_form() {
global $product;

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );
woocommerce_quantity_input(
    array(
        'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
        'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
        'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
    )
);
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
```

}`

like i say its bring me the quantity box to the top, i want it right above the "Add to cart" button. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

After you have copied your template you can edit it freely

Replace your code piece with this

```
<div class="qty-row">
    <span><?php echo __('Select Qantity','text-domain'); ?></span>
<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

woocommerce_quantity_input(
    array(
        'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
        'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
        'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
    )
);

do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
?>
</div>
```

Now we have wraped our qty in extra div. Depending on your theme may or may not need additional css.

```
.qty-row {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.qty-row span {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

if you want text and qty lined remove width from `.qty-row span`. By default quantity is float left so we need span to be floated too. Like i said you may not need any additional css changes.

Comment: hi i try to use ur solution but its bring me the button right next to the add to cart button not above him. i need it above him. if i drag and drop the div in the console to upper position its fixed. thats what i need to do with the css but i dont know how

Comment: i solved it by moving the `qty-div` above the `<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">`. thanks!

Comment: Like i said you may need css depending on your theme. Glad you solved it